# Magento 2 grunt:exec removes all static files

Tags: magento2, static-content, grunt

Magento 2 `grunt exec:theme_name` removes all static files, then adds only less files. Yesterday everything was working correctly, today suddenly it's not working. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First remove all the contents inside the pub/static folder

```
rm -rf ./pub/static/*
```

After that you can run

```
grunt refresh
```

Then run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This should resolve the issue.